# how to debug RMI/IIOP through internet?

Tags: java, networking, rmi, iiop

I have a client/server applciation that communicates through JNDI/RMI/IIOP using, on client side, some Glassfish client code (NOT packaged as a Glassfish client) and on server side a Glassfish instance.

I have some Glassfish multimode scripts that I use to make sure the domains I create on any machines are totally identical and correctly configured.

Using that script on local network, I have already made sure I could access a remote Glassfish server instance from client code on my machine (that was quite a reasonable guess, however I tend to test all things I'm not totally sure of).

Next step is to have that client/server application working over (I should instead say "through") internet : with my client code in my company LAN (in other words on my machine) and my server code on an Amazon VM running my Glassfish server. For some reasons, the remote Glassfish is running on a Windows VM.

Obviously (as I ask that question, you can safely guess the through internet test is NOT working. And you're right.

So, to have more guesses, I started [SmartSniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) both on my machine and on server.

On my machine, I can only see one TCP packet going to that server instance (and nothing coming back).

On server instance, I can see one packet entering (the client query) and one packet exiting (the server answer). That server answer looks like this :

> [4/4/2012 11:47:13 AM:917]
>   GIOP.......(................NameService....._is_a...................NEO................ª.......(IDL:omg.org/SendingContext/CodeBase:1.0............n........172.27.63.145.Ô2....¯«Ë........e...........................
>   ...................
>   ...   ...........&...............(IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext:1.0.

That 172.27.63.145 address is my IP in local network.

> [4/4/2012 11:47:13 AM:917]
>   GIOP.......2............NEO................0.......(IDL:omg.org/SendingContext/CodeBase:1.0............ô........46.137.114.###.'5....¯«Ë........d...........................
>   ...................
>   ...   ...........&...........!...|...............$...
>   ...f............10.241.42.###.'6.@........g..............g........default...................g...............+IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContextExt:1.0.............¢........10.241.42.208.'5...M¯«Ë....
>   ...d...   S1AS-ORB............RootPOA....
>   TNameService............................... ...................
>   ...   ...........&......

That 46.137.114.### is external one of my Amazon VM, and 10.241.42.### is its internal IP in amazon magical virtual server.

So it seems server is answering, no ?

But that answer never finds its way to my machine in my network.

So ... how can I check where it get lost ? Seems likepacket sniffer has done its job, but what can I do now ?

**NOTE** This question is a clarification of ["How to Connect a glassfish client to glassfish server over NATs?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9890597/15619)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps stupid question, but is your Amazon EC2 instance is configured with all required ports   open for your communication protocol to work? You could see configured open ports in security group your instance assigned to in AWS console, under EC2->Security Groups.